# For all integers $m,\,n$, prove $\max(m,\,n)+\min(m,\,n) = m + n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> For all integers $m,\,n$, prove $\max(m,\,n)+\min(m,\,n) = m + n$

This is a discrete mathematics questions, there are no specific proof method asked. I am quite confused because this is the first time I was given a Max and Min question. Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Welcome to math.se. What happens if $m\ge n$? What happens if $m<n$? (@Wuestenfux's answer explains why you don't need to check the second case anyway.)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA [is right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial). I've made some formatting changes (see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how).

Comment: While I agree with the elegance in the answer of Wuestenfux, I also recommend against this elegance for students new to the topic of max and min.  Instead, I recommend the inelegant approach of : $~\underline{\text{Case 1 :} ~m \geq n~}$ and $~\underline{\text{Case 2 :} ~m < n}.$

Answer (score 3):

[Without restriction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Without_loss_of_generality) one can assume that $m\geq n$. Then $\max(m,n)=m$ and $\min(m,n)=n$. Thus the sum will be $m+n$.